# How to create a static constant in a class using TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

How to create an TypeScript static constant in a class?
That mean I can refer a constant without initialize the class.
This is my class:

```
export class CallTree{
    public static readonly active = 1;
    ............................
}
```

The component's html is something like the following:

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="callTreeList" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8 callTreeList">
    ...............................

  <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Status</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [innerHTML]="(element.status === CallTree.active)?'Active':'Inactive'"></td>
   </ng-container>
```

The browser console prompt the following error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'active' of undefined
```

How can I fix the problem?
How can I use this constant in the Angular component's html?

Comment: Where are you calling the console.log()?

Comment: I don't think your declaration of static const is wrong, as @LloydNicholson said, from where you are calling it might be wrong.

Comment: In the component's html.

Comment: can you post the code in question the code for component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can import the class and refer the class property in you components.

assume you have your constant class in the `const.class.ts` file

`import { CallTree } from './const.class'`

```
export class AppComponent  {

  name = CallTree.active;    

}
```

Comment: Your answer inspired me to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare like this

```
export class CallTree{

static readonly: number = 1;

}
```

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-static